# How to get reaction collector on embed sent by the bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was using something like this but i want it to look for reactions in the embed sent! not in the message

```
const collector = message.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => 
    user.id === message.author.id &&
    reaction.emoji.name === "◀" ||
    reaction.emoji.name === "▶" ||
    reaction.emoji.name === "❌"
).once("collect", reaction => {
    const chosen = reaction.emoji.name;
    if(chosen === "◀"){
        // Prev page
    }else if(chosen === "▶"){
        // Next page
    }else{
        // Stop navigating pages
    }
    collector.stop();
});
```

Comment: The embed is part of the message. In fact, you can't react to an embed; you're reacting to the message itself.

Comment: So is it not possible to get reaction collector in an embed? Also can leave me a message on discord Username I LIKE TURTLES#7053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed) is sent as part of a message. Therefore, when you add a reaction, it's on the message, not the embed.

See the example below which gives the *appearance* of reactions on an embed.

```js
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');

var embed = new RichEmbed()
  .setTitle('**Test**')
  .setDescription('React with the emojis.');

message.channel.send(embed)
  .then(async msg => {
    // Establish reaction collector

    for (emoji of ['◀', '▶', '❌']) await msg.react(emoji);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```